# Why does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(-1)^n \cdot n^2 + 1} = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits

As the title suggests, I want to know as to why the following function converges to 1 for $n \to \infty$:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(-1)^n \cdot n^2 + 1} = 1
$$

For even $n$'s only $n^2+1$ has to be shown, which I did in the following way:

$$\sqrt[n]{n^2} \le \sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1} \le \sqrt[n]{n^3}$$

Assuming we have already proven that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^k} = 1$ we can conclude that

$$1 \le \sqrt[n]{n^2+1} \le 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+1} = 1.$$

For odd $n$'s I can't find the solution. I tried going the same route as for even $n$'s:

$$\sqrt[n]{-n^2} \le \sqrt[n]{-n^2 + 1} \le \sqrt[n]{-n^3}$$

And it seems that it comes down to

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{-n^k}$$

I checked the limit using both [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+nth+root+of+%28-n%5Ek%29+as+n+-%3E+infinity) and a CAS and it converges to 1. Why is that?

Comment: It's a good question.

Comment: I do not think the limit is 1, since $\sqrt[2n+1]{-(2n+1)^2}$ converges towards $-1$.

Comment: @zuggg I thought the same thing,[Wolfram Alpha doesn't](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28-%282n%2B1%29%5Ek%29%5E%281%2F%282n%2B1%29%29+as+n+-%3E+infinity).

Comment: Well, then it depends how you define the $n$th root, because any real number $\not=0$ has exactly $n$ $n$th roots.

Comment: @zuggg: however, I don't think I've seen any definition of cube root in which $\sqrt[3]{-1}=1$.

Comment: I checked by Maple with/without the MultiSeries package. Without is undefined, with is 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $n=2p+1$ we have
$$\sqrt[n]{(-1)^n \cdot n^2 + 1}=-\exp\left(\frac{1}{2p+1}\log((2p+1)^2-1)\right)\longrightarrow_{p\to\infty}-e^0=-1$$
The case $n=2p$ is almost similar and we find the limit $1$ so the given limit is undefined.

Comment: $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2p+1}\log((2p+1)^2-1)\right)=\exp\left(-\log\left( \left( (2p+1)^2-1 \right)^{\frac{1}{2p+1}}\right) \right)$

$=\frac{1}{\left( (2p+1)^2-1 \right)^{\frac{1}{2p+1}}}$. On the other hand if $n\geq 3$ is odd then $(-1)^n \cdot n^2 + 1<-1$ so $\sqrt[n]{(-1)^n \cdot n^2 + 1}<-1$ ant the limit cannot $1$.

Comment: I placed the sign $-$ in the wrong place and I edited my answer.

Comment: Now it is correct :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @SamiBenRomdhane. If it is not too much of a hassle, could you (or someone else) elaborate on how you get the $exp$ function from the $n$-th root?

Comment: @Pit Sami just used the facts that $x = \exp(\log(x))$, $\log(x^y) = y\log(x)$, and taking the $n$-th root is the same as raising to the $\frac{1}{n}$-th power for positive reals.

Comment: @MartianInvader Ah, thank you very much, that was the missing piece in the puzzle for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

It's common for CAS's like Wolfram Alpha to take $n$th roots that are complex numbers with the smallest angle measured counterclockwise from the positive real axis. So the $n$th root of negative real numbers winds up being in the first quadrant of the complex plane. As $n\to\infty$, this $n$th root would get closer to the real axis and explain why WA says the limit is 1. CAS's do this for continuity reasons; so that $\sqrt[n]{-2}$ will be close to $\sqrt[n]{-2+\varepsilon\,i}$.

Instead of $\sqrt[n]{x}$, you can get around the issue with $\operatorname{sg}(x)\cdot\sqrt[n]{|x|}$ where $\operatorname{sg}(x)$ is the signum function: $1$ for positive $x$ and $-1$ for negative $x$.

Answer (score 0):

take out the (-1)^n outside the bracket and solve to get -1 as the answer, but didn't get 1